# Docker Odoo - PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/odoo/sessions'

Tags: docker, odoo

That was my first time create a project with Docker.

This it URL github my project : https://github.com/ngocnhi10011999/odoo-docker

The problems was appear when I run

```
sh dev up
```

and browser port 8069

ERROR

`
PermissionError

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/odoo/sessions'
Traceback (most recent call last)

```
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 112, in application

return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 87, in application_unproxied

result = odoo.http.root(environ, start_response)

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1336, in __call__

return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1302, in __call__

return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/middleware/shared_data.py", line 260, in __call__

return self.app(environ, start_response)

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1487, in dispatch

explicit_session = self.setup_session(httprequest)

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1367, in setup_session

session_gc(self.session_store)

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/func.py", line 26, in __get__

value = self.fget(obj)

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1313, in session_store

path = odoo.tools.config.session_dir

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/config.py", line 710, in session_dir

os.makedirs(d, 0o700)

File "/usr/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 225, in makedirs

mkdir(name, mode)

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/odoo/sessions'
```

`

Comment: Can you please try sudo chmod +x  dev , from the project root first ?

Comment: @ShamithWimukthi thanks, I ran `docker exec -it --user root <your container id> /usr/bin/odoo scaffold openacademy //var/lib/odoo/sessions`, and it pass error

Comment: And now, it raise error AssertionError: /var/lib/odoo/sessions: directory is not writable

Comment: https://repo1.dso.mil/dsop/opensource/odoo/odoo/-/issues/3 check this link , it says volume error

Comment: @ShamithWimukthi   Thanks for your enthusiasm!.  It only run chown odoo:odoo -R odoo folder